# Change the text color just clicked not all

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list and I need that when you click the div "accordionHead" change only i clicked one for one, no all.

```
$('.accordionHead').each( function(){
  $(this).bind('click', function(){
      $(this).find('h2 a').css("color", "green");
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92p3enp3/1/)

Comment: It seems to work correctly for me.

Comment: Your fiddle is working what you say!

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use `.each()`. And you should use `.on()` or `.click()` instead of `.bind()`.

Comment: Also it's a good idea to fix HTML, which is incorrect (you have `</i>` inside each `<a>` without opening tag `<i>`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a css class and on click of it add that class on the anchor tag and remove it from the other anchor tags that have that class already.

```
.green
{
    color:green
}
```

Like this:

```
$('.accordionHead').on('click', function(){
      $('h2 a.green').removeClass("green");
      $(this).find('h2 a').addClass("green");
  });
```

### UPDATED FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/92p3enp3/3/

Answer (score 0):

give this a shot:

```
$('.accordionHead').each( function(){
  $(this).bind('click', function(){
      $(this).find('h2 a:gt(1)').css("color", "green");
  });
});
```

Comment: I need to just stay in the green, which was clicked.

Comment: Would be helpful if you can add some explanation to the answer

Comment: :gt  is a jQuery selector that says grab all elements Greater Than (x)

Answer (score 0):

Below will do the trick

```
$('.accordionHead').each( function(){
  $(this).bind('click', function(){
      $('.accordionHead').find('h2 a').removeClass('color');
      $(this).find('h2 a').addClass('color');
  });
});
```